# Using a Flask app as an interface to a non web-related program

Tags: python, flask

I guess this is a question about best practices.

I'm a bit new to web development, web frameworks, etc.  I'm planning to make a website with Flask.  I'm curious about making an app that's an interface to what would essentially be a command-line program.  Say, for example, I have a Python command-line program that accepts a word and prints out all valid anagrams of that word.  Where/how would this logic fit into my Flask app?  Would it be something like this?

```
from anagram import compute_all_anagrams

@app.route("/result?word=<word>") # I'm not sure if this is correct usage of route
def result_page(word):
    result = compute_all_anagrams(word) # returns a list of anagrams
    render_template("result.html", result=result)
```

Where result.html is a template that displays a list of results?

Of course, here I wouldn't be having my anagram program *print* anything, but rather return it as an array of strings.

Additionally, what if compute_all_anagrams takes a while--say 10 seconds? How would that change things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you've got the idea.

If things are going to take a long time to compute, you can look into using ajax or similar client-side "rendering..." messages.  So then you'd spawn a background job - the easiest way is actually running an external process altogether - and then each time the "is it done yet?" request comes in, you check if it's still running, and if not, return the result (from a file, say), and if it is still running, then tell the client so.

By default the flask built-in development webserver will block when you are doing long things in the foreground - which is bad for multi-user stuff, but fine for single-user "I just want to control a few tasks from my phone".  Which is why there are many other servers you can plug flask or any other normal python web framework into.  These are called WSGI servers.  A good 'default' one is 'waitress' http://waitress.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, which is a pure python server, so doesn't need any extra libs or anything.  Also good are the gevent WSGI server, gunicorn, uwsgi...  But it doesn't really matter for small single (or few) user apps.

If you're putting things on the internet, so the public can access them, then often it's a good idea to hide your flask app behind nginx (or similar) as a "reverse proxy", which can limit the number of requests without freaking out, and just generally keep things sane.

But anyway, 10 seconds is quite OK for response times for a long computing task.  If things are going to take longer than a minute, then I'd say you should certainly look into some kind of external process for these tasks, and monitoring it.

You do need to be careful that others can't start jobs like this though - it's easy to get your computer DOS'd by many people all requesting jobs which take a very long time to compute.  You should stick password (at least!) protection over such services.

Your use of route is wrong though - `/result/<word>` is enough.  Anything after the ? isn't actually part of the route - it's a request argument.  You can access those through the flask.request object (check the docs).

Have fun! :-)